# Enable running mono apps by double-clicking on the .exe file

Tags: linux, mono

I always wondered if running Mono apps will ever be available for Linux by just double clicking on the `.exe`. Now, in order to have a launcher on GNOME, the best way is to add a new bash file which will do the 'mono myapp.exe' for you.

I remember there were some ideas to have that in Linux long time ago, but nothing recently...

Comment: I don't know about mono apps, but Ubuntu can run `.exe` files through WINE by double clicking. I think it mono will be just the same.

Comment: idk why not... it's really a matter of just telling your DE to handle the extension by executing it. ( of course the file must be marked executable )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has this by default, AFAIK.  For an idea of how this might work, take a look at: [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)

Comment: @flipm0de Look in /var/lib/binfmts/cli if you're interested in how it's registered and/or if you want to change which runtime is used to run the app.